# Adding <meta> redirect using Greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey, meta-tags, userscripts

I'm looking to add `<meta>` element to specific websites using Greasemonkey script. The idea is to redirect the website to another page after `X` minutes. Something like below:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="60; URL=http://example.com">
```

What is the simplest way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Greasemonkey (or JavaScript) to add the `meta` node, but it won't be parsed (at least in FF 4.0).   AFAIK, browsers are only expected to parse `meta` directives on initial load.

You can use JavaScript to "redirect" the page, after an interval, like so:

```
setTimeout (function() {
    window.location.href    = "http://example.com";
    },
    60000 //-- 60 seconds
);
```

---

If you don't want the original page to remain in the browser's history, use:

```
setTimeout (function() {
    window.location.replace ("http://example.com");
    },
    60000 //-- 60 seconds
);
```